# Make a JDialog sit until user has disposed properly

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I extended `JDialog` and made it modal, etc.

How do I make it not return from the dialog until the user has selected OK button or Cancel and the dialog has been disposed?

I don't want to add a thread and have it spinning. I just want it to wait until user disposes.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to make it `modal`?

Comment: Do you mean "not return" like the `showConfirmDialog()` method of [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)?

Comment: Also, it would help if you show the code you use to create and display the dialog.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `setVisible()` function, and check the status before you allow `setVisible(false);`.